# Draggable jquery popup window

Tags: php, jquery

I have a draggable jquery popup window,now its shows a message inside its body.But i want to load a html page inside the popup how can i do this

here is the screen shot of my popup

[image]

here is my code
popup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #draggable { width: 200px; height: 250px; background: silver; }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#draggable").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:75%;">

    <div id="draggable">Drag me</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using with `.load()` and make it `.draggable()` too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable").load('yourtargetpage.php').draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#draggable').load('filetoload.html');
```